# How to filter occupation as you type in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, filter

I have a list of 2500 occupations held in our db.  On our site we ask for you to enter your occupation and I would like it to filter the results as they type; like Play.com's search.  Is there a way to do this in MVC3?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a autocomplete javascript.

For example: 
http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/jQueryAutoCompleteASPNETMVCFramework.aspx

You can grab your data using jQuery Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an action method that would return JSON:

```
        [HttpGet()]
        public JsonResult Occupations(String searchCriteria)
        {
            String[] occupations = new String[] { "Lawyer", "Carpenter" };
            return Json(occupations.Where(s => s.Contains(searchCriteria))
                                   .ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

If you run a GET request on this link: /Occupations?searchCriteria=Carpenter you'll receive ["Carpenter"] in a response.

I would make a jQuery ajax call to this action method. On success, I would take a reponse and generate an output such as list of li elements to select from.

Example of an ajax json get request is below:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'json',
            url: '/Occupations',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { searchCriteria: searchCriteria},
            error: function () {

            },
            success: function (result) {               
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

This is from a notepad, so there might be some minor syntax errors.